# Starksoft GPG wrapper

Tags: vb.net, gnupg

I am having trouble with some VB code that was working on Windows 2003 and now moved to Windows 2008.

Using Starksoft gpg wrapper, I am getting a generic failure message: "Request failed"

```
Dim gnu As GnuPG = New GnuPG
Dim strmFOUT As System.IO.FileStream = New System.IO.FileStream(StrFileOut + ".txt",    IO.FileMode.Create)
gnu.BinaryPath = "c:\Program Files (x86)\GNU\GnuPG\"

gnu.Recipient = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("GNURecipient")
gnu.Encrypt(msStream, strmFOUT)
```

I have tried:
 1. Validating gpg can encrypt a file with the recipient provided
 2. Put displays in to validate the correct recipient id is being pass
 3. Tried with and without assigning the `BinaryPath` variable and with and without a trailing  "\"

All of the test/development environments are server 2003 and I can only get it to fail on 2008.

Any Ideas?